# Failed to load the GDAL native libs for GeoServer 2.15.0

Tags: geoserver, open-source-gis

2 days searching and looking for a guideline to enable GDAL extension for GeoServer, I found many questions here and I followed all steps, but unfortunately the problem still exist the default raster extension not changed.

I just need a clear guideline how to enable GDAL, ECW, MrSID extensions for GeoServer 2.15.0

edit:
error message

WARNING: Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.

[image: error message]

Comment: if your question is substantially different please indicate this by editing your question so that it enters the reopen queue

Comment: i changed the title and added a screenshot of the error